# Bootstrap Menu list item dropdown not button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I am having difficulties of using bootstrap's navigation bar. I would like to create a dropdown menu list using bootstrap. The problem is that the li is on the navigation bar. I know bootstrap has dropdown but its for buttons which in this case is not appropriate. How can i have a ul li a dropdown in my bootstrap navigation bar? For example lets assume that i have 5 pages and i want page to be be visible and when i click to show below the other 4 pages? I would like to create a navigation dropdown using ul inside a navigation bar using bootstrap

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a great example site, consider using chrome devtools or similar to look at the source code, you can easily reuse the whole source or whichever part you desire.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Inspecting the 'Dropdown' button you will see the ul li a structure you desire

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

<!-- libraries needed: jquery & bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: yea i can use the code but its using buttons inside navbar... is there a way to do a dropdown using ul li a ?

Comment: Inspect the 'Dropdown' button, you will see that it uses ul li a

Comment: i have copy ur code but its not working it will not dropdown and show the hide li inside the dropdown. Can u help me with that?

Comment: Are you asking how to build a bootstrap dropdown within a dropdown?

Comment: I would like to build a dropdown inside bootstrap navbar without using buttons, only ul li a

Comment: If you look at all of the elements shown in my original post you will note that none of them are <button> I believe this post answers the original question.

Comment: I would like to be like the dropdown button but when i paste ur code and try to click the button it does not work

Comment: i think what you were looking for was multiple select https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want : 
Follow the link :

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h

Comment: You should write the code instead the link